# How to filter Records by category in PHP Laravel Twig?

Tags: php, laravel, twig, octobercms

I'm making a simple gallery using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/pagination), based on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination) and [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org).

How can I filter records by category?

Here is how I'm doing it now, but I don't think this is a good solution:

I filter the html, but the full records still exists for all the items outside the category, causing extra pagination and blank pages.

**Database**

- A Table 'gallery' holds list of category names.
- A Table 'images' holds the image names and their tagged categories.

**Image List**

The URL parameters are /gallery/:category?/:page?

Visiting a url like /gallery/nature/1 will filter images by category using a for loop.

```
<!-- Gallery Category Record Variable -->
{% set category = record.category %}

<!-- Image List -->
{% for record in records %}

    <!-- If Image Category Tag matches Gallery Category Name -->
    {% if record.category_tag == category %} 
        <img src="/{{ record.name }}.jpg">
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

**Records**

Results for 'records' and 'record'.

The for loop is showing 'gallery→category' record in 'images→category_tag' records.

The pagination is showing all 'images→name' records.

```
{% for record in records %} = (All in 'images')
{{ records }} = {<ul><li>...<a href="gallery/nature?page=2">2</a>} (All in 'images')
{{ record }} = {"category":"nature","id":7} (Current category in 'gallery')
```

**Solution?**

Is there a way to filter the 'records' by category before generating the html list?

Comment: Not sure if I misunderstood but, isn't it simpler to fetch records that matches the criteria before passing it to the view? like `Gallery::where('category_id', $catId)->get()`.  Of course you'd first have to fetch the category ID using the name taken from the parameters

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Through OctoberCMS you drag and drop Record List or Record Details, then set the Model Class and Display Column. From there you can use Twig syntax to use the records. I'm new to this and using Laravel outside of Twig.

Comment: My bad, the link for OctoberCMS redirected to the pagination page, so I assumed it was just a pagination component (even though the name said CMS, silly me hahaha)

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco I've taken your advice and trying with Gallery::select()->where()->paginate(); It's working with some problems, like CurrentPage value missing.

Comment: It is better to do the filtering in your component, a nice example would be the RainLab Blog Plugin, have a look how it filters posts by category

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would approach it :

- Create a Scope in your Images Model that filters by Page, Category ect..
- Handle the URL properties and logic in your component not view

Let's say Gallery Component :

URL : page.com/:cat/:page?

```
    public function defineProperties()
    {
        return [
            // Page # for pagination..
            'pageNumber' => [
                'title'       => 'Page #',
                'description' => 'Gallery Page #',
                'type'        => 'string',
                'default'     => '{{ :page }}',
            ],
            // Category slug
            'category' => [
                'title'       => 'Category',
                'description' => 'Gallery Cat',
                'type'        => 'string',
                'default'     => '{{ :cat }}',
            ],
            // Images to show per page
            'perPage' => [
                'title'             => 'Images per page',
                'type'              => 'string',
                'validationPattern' => '^[0-9]+$', //  validation
                'validationMessage' =>  'VValidation Error',
                'default'           => '15', 
            ],
            // if you want to add sorting
            'sortOrder' => [
                'title'       => 'Sort Order',
                'description' => 'Images Sort Order',
                'type'        => 'dropdown',
                'default'     => 'updated_at desc' 
            ],
        ];
    }

public function getSortOrderOptions()
{
    return Image::$allowedSortingOptions;
}


public function init()
{
    $this->pageNumber   =  empty($this->property('pageNumber')) ? 1 :   $this->property('pageNumber');
    $this->perPage      =  $this->property('perPage');
    $this->sortOrder    =  $this->property('sortOrder');
    $this->category     =  $this->property('category');
}

public function onRun()
{

  // here you may want to do some checks 
 // and add logic before querying your DB

    return $this->listImages($this->pageNumber , $this->sortOrder,  $this->perPage, $this->category);

}

public function listImages($pageNumber, $sortOrder, $perPage, $category){

  // this is the scope you will define in your Images Model
 // to handle pagination, sorting, category filtering ect..

    $images = Images::listFrontEnd([
        'page'          => $pageNumber,
        'sort'          => $sortOrder,
        'perPage'       => $perPage,
        'category'      => $category,
    ]);



   // small helper if the pagination # is > than last page
  // redirect to last page..

    $lastPage = $images->lastPage();

    if ($this->pageNumber > $lastPage && $this->pageNumber > 1){
            return Redirect::to($this->currentPageUrl(["page" =>  $lastPage]));
        }


 $this->images  = $this->page['images'] = $images;

}
```

in your Image Model :

```
// list the allowed sorting options that will show up in your component

public static $allowedSortingOptions = array(
    'created_at asc'            => 'Images Created (ascending)',
    'created_at desc'           => 'Images Created (descending)',
    'updated_at asc'            => 'Images Updated (ascending)',

  //        ect....
);


// Scope for your component
public function scopelistImages($query, $options)
    {
        /*
         * Default options
         */
        extract(array_merge([
            'page'              => 1,
            'perPage'           => 15,
            'sort'              => 'updated_at',
            'category'          => null
        ], $options));



        // SORTING
        if (!is_array($sort)) {
            $sort = [$sort];
        }

        foreach ($sort as $_sort) {

            if (in_array($_sort, array_keys(self::$allowedSortingOptions))) {
                $parts = explode(' ', $_sort);
                if (count($parts) < 2) {
                    array_push($parts, 'desc');
                }
                list($sortField, $sortDirection) = $parts;
                if ($sortField == 'random') {
                    $sortField = Db::raw('RAND()');
                }
                $query->orderBy($sortField, $sortDirection);
            }
        }

        // Filter by category
         ........


        return $query->paginate($perPage, $page);
    }
```

Answer inspired from the [RainLab Blog Plugin](https://github.com/rainlab/blog-plugin/blob/master/components/Posts.php)